# Remote Job execution with non terminating Return

Tags: powershell, return, powershell-remoting

I have a script that I am running both remotely and locally in different situations. In the remote situations I would like to return some additional job information. However, the script also needs to complete with a Restart, LogOff, etc.

However, if I `Return $Results`, no code that follows is executed. Whereas if I `Write-Host` the return info, I see it as additional data for the job, and the script completion code that follows can still execute.

I can make this work, but it causes two issues.

1. I have two bits of data I need to return, which I had planned to do in an array. But with `Write-Host` I need to use the kludge of `$value1|$value2` and then split the string on | to get at the two bits of data.
2. `Write-Host` somewhat pollutes my console so I need some extra code to manage that.

Is there any way to return intermediate info and continue execution? Or am I going to have no choice but to go the `Write-Host` route? Or is there perhaps another approach that is better than the `Write-Host` hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that you have to use the `return` keyword to make a function(?) return something. PowerShell works a little differently, though. PowerShell functions return the entire non-captured output on the success output stream. The `return` keyword is just for making a function return at that particular point.

There is no difference at all between

```psh
function Foo {
  return 'something'   # return with value
}
```

and

```psh
function Foo {
  'something'
  return               # echo first, then return
}
```

and

```psh
function Foo {
  'something'          # just echo, return implicitly
}
```

That way you can have a function generate the output, then do more stuff before actually returning:

```psh
function Foo {
  'foo'
  'bar'
  Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | Out-Null  # output not returned (suppressed)
  'baz' > 'C:\some.txt'                # output not returned (redirected to file)
}
```

The caller will receive the returned values (in this case `'foo', 'bar'`) only after the function call returns, though. If you need immediate feedback you'll need other means.

Comment: He's referring to a Job, not a function, but same theory really. I like to think of it as all output for the job/function/script is returned to the pipeline unless otherwise explicitly redirected (such as the use of cmdlet like `Out-File` or `Write-Host`). Pretty much what you said, I just like the phrasing 'unless otherwise explicitly redirected'

Comment: If it's a Job, you can output to any of the the streams (Verbose, Warning, or Debug) and read each stream independently without doing a Receive-Job.  If the issue is just getting 2 different pieces of information, you could write one to each of 2 different streams and then read each one for the relevant return.

Comment: "The return keyword is just for making a function return at that particular point." Aha! I did know that functions don't require return, but I was somehow under the impression that jobs did. In any case, this bit above clarified what is really going on, which is good to know. Thanks Ansgar. Mjolinor, am I understanding correctly that the streams approach is really only needed for returning intermediate status? In my case I only need final status, but good to have a more flexible approach in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Return.  Just output $Results, and let the rest of the script continue on.